# Lambda call on Android randomly fails

Tags: android, lambda, java-8, android-jack-and-jill

Just started using lambdas in a new project and stuck with the issue when app crashes with the following stack trace:

```
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.test.-$Lambda$3>
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test, PID: 18852
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.test.-$Lambda$3
    ... method which calls lambda ...
```

The interesting thing is it works sometimes but I still can't figure out what makes it work and what breaks.

`jackOptions` and `1.8 compatibility` are both enabled in build.gradle. `compileSdkVersion` is 25. Device is running Android 5.0. The resulting apk has this `com.test.-$Lambda$3`class defined.

Is there anything that should be done in addition to completely enable lambdas? How to debug this issue to find out the real root cause?

**Update 1:**

It sounds pretty strange but looks like compiler messes with lambda calls. Say the resulting APK has `$Lambda$1:Runnable` and `$Lambda$2:Consumer` defined and I see particular method calls `$Lambda$1` while it has to be `$Lambda$2`.

Comment: Not so familiar with Android but I think Android doesn't support java-8 yet. Also it seems weird the error that your app yields. The definition of the Lambda seems weird. Can you share the code too? Worth to check https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html

Comment: @xiumeteo I've done everything according tot that guide. The funny thing it was working till some point and then suddenly stopped, then started again and then stopped completely.